# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
waitTime=0.5

def is_ava():
    waitTime = waitTime + 0.1
    print waitTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_ava()
```

Why `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'waitTime' referenced before assignment` , I have declared waitTime.

Python version: 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To modify global variable, you need to [declare it inside the function as a global variable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

```
waitTime=0.5

def is_ava():
    global waitTime  # <--------
    waitTime = waitTime + 0.1
    print waitTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_ava()
```

Comment: What if I want to modify a `global` name in two different functions? Do I have to declare it in each function?

Comment: @zyy, Yes you do.